# unordered lists as columns

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to use unordered lists as columns something setup like the following:

```
<ul>
<li>word 1</li>
<li>word 1</li>
<li>word 1</li>
<li>word 1</li>
<li>word 1</li>
</ul>
 <ul>
 <li>word 2</li>
 <li>word 2</li>
 <li>word 2</li>
 <li>word 2</li>
 <li>word 2</li>
 </ul>
```

What would I need to do as far as css these to lineup side by side as vertical lists with no bullets.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I can't seem to figure it out.  I specifically need this to work in IE7.

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Answer (score 6):

Here's the really short answer:

```
ul {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Here's the slightly longer explanation:

- The `float` part tells your lists to move together "on the same line". You might want to add a `width` property to the `ul` elements as well, in order to get equally distributed columns.
- The `list-style-type` property simply turns off your bullets. Most likely, you will now have empty space where the bullets used to be. This can be removed by overriding `maring` and `padding` - eg. set them both to zero.

You might also want to add a `clear: left` property on whatever element is following the lists.

Comment: `list-type-style` is something I've not seen before, is it a synonym for `list-style-type` or a typo?

Comment: @ricebowl: That would be the result of me being tired. It's fixed now. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrapper">
<ul>
<li>word 1</li>
<li>word 1</li>
<li>word 1</li>
<li>word 1</li>
<li>word 1</li>
</ul>
 <ul>
 <li>word 2</li>
 <li>word 2</li>
 <li>word 2</li>
 <li>word 2</li>
 <li>word 2</li>
 </ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
ul {width: 40%; float: left;list-style-type: none;}
ul li {list-style-type: none;}
.clear {clear:both;font-size:0px;line-height:0px;height:0px;}
</style>
```

Something along those lines... keep in mind that this will look quite a bit more "standard" between browsers if you have a decent CSS reset block.  I recommend Blueprint.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
<div id="menucontainer">
  <ul>
    <li>w1</li>
    <li>w2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#menucontainer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#menucontainer ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0.1em;
}
```